# Generating documentation for multiple folders with Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am currently working on a Python project that is growing bigger than expected.
My code is documented all throughout with docstrings, and I would now like to generate a comprehensive documentation with Sphinx.
However, no matter what I try, I can't figure out a way to generate everything in a single command.

Here is the **updated** structure of my project:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── _build
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
├── project
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   └── file2.py
│   ├── ext_files
│   │   └── >files we dont care about
│   ├── module2
│   │   ├── file3.py
│   │   ├── file4.py
│   │   └── file5.py
│   ├── module3
│   │   ├── file6.py
│   │   ├── file7.py
│   │   ├── file8.py
│   │   └── file9.py
│   └── main.py
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

Ideally, I would like an HTML documentation that follows this structure.

What I've tried:

- `sphinx-quickstart`, giving proper info
- Then editing the `conf.py` file, adding `sphinx.ext.autodoc`, `sphinx.ext.napoleon` as well as a `sys.path.abspath(..)` (shortened)
- Using `sphinx-apidoc` on my 3 different folders in many different ways
- Moving around the `.rst` files in subdirectories in my main docs directory
- Modifying the `index.rst` and/or `modules.rst` and adding the names of my folders/files to them

I've also tried manually adding `automodule` directives, as well as creating submodules.
I've tried setting up `sphinx-autogen` to discover my different modules automatically.
However, no matter what I do, it either only generates documentation for my main.py file or nothing at all.

Please help me, as I am going crazy. No matter what tutorial I follow or documentation I read, I can't seem to find an answer.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: sphinx and Python projects are *usually* structured with a common package name (e.g. `myhandlers`) and subpackages are created under it as necessary (e.g.: `myhandlers.misc_handlers`, `.data_handlers`, etc.). The structure shown above departs from the standard, so it might be *trickier* than usual to get this working. Is this a legacy codebase where refactoring is difficult?

Comment: You can learn the conventions from existing projects, such as https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp and https://www.pysnmp.com/pysnmp/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments. I have updated my structure (reflected in the original post). However, I still can't manage to generate the full documentation for all the modules. I changed my sys path to '../project' in conf.py, and used sphinx-apidoc. main.py is still the only file with a generated documentation! Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying pretty much everything, I solved it by:

1. Updating my project structure to reflect the one above (inspired by the link given by Lex Li)
2. Deleted all my sphinx files, re-ran `sphinx-quickstart`, made sure to separate build and source
3. Made sure every subfolder of `project` had a `__init__.py` file
4. From the `docs/source` folder, edited my `conf.py` file and added

```
import os
import sys
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'project'))
sys.path.insert(0, basedir)
```

5. Added `sphinx.ext.autodoc` and `sphinx.ext.napoleon` to the extensions
6. Added `modules` under the toctree directive in `index.rst`
7. From the docs folder, ran `sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ../project -f --separate`
8. Then, from `docs/`, ran `make html`.

After running `sphinx-apidoc`, make sure a `<module>.rst` file is generated for each module you have or need documented.

I feel like this detailed answer could be useful to someone, as it is somewhat the compilation of multiple StackOverflow answers.

Please note that my project directory looks like this:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   └── source
├── project
│   ├── module1
│   ├── module2
│   ├── module3
└── └── module4
└── tests
```

Comment: I am having this problem currently and following what you went through to fix it. I have one question as it seems confusing. I am running on windows so maybe it is different structure but why have you run this ```sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ../project -f``` surely you actually ran ```sphinx-apidoc -o ./docs ../project -f``` or did I misunderstand something? But how does your line create the docs in the docs folder if you have pointed it to /source for the output?

Comment: Hello,
I have a `docs` folder, containing separate `build` and `source` folders.
When running sphinx-quickstart, there is an option to separate build and source, which I use.
My project directory looks like this (. being the root), I run the above command from the docs folder.
. => docs, project, tests, venv |
docs => build, source |
project => module1, module2, etc.

Comment: @Koreos do you also have access to reference code in your tests folder from your rst files?